# CSS selector select <p> not having <a>

Tags: html, css

I have the following html

```html
<p>Aurora and Milky Way over Norway</p>
<p>Image Credit &amp; Copyright: Giulio Cobianchi</p>
<p><a href="https://apod.nasa.gov/apod/ap231212.html" rel=
"nofollow noopener noreferrer" target="_blank"><span class=
"invisible">https://</span><span class=
"ellipsis">apod.nasa.gov/apod/ap231212.ht</span><span class=
"invisible">ml</span></a> <a href="https://botsin.space/tags/APOD"
class="mention hashtag" rel="nofollow noopener noreferrer" target=
"_blank">#<span>APOD</span></a></p>
```

Can I use CSS selector to select `<p>` that only contains text? (the first two `<p>` only)

Comment: In modern browsers your can do `p:not(:has(a))`, but support for that isn't universal yet. There is no CSS selector to do this otherwise, best to add a class with JS or something in that case.

Comment: I would not say in modern browsers. In updated major browser. Firefox is a modern browser but only supports it with the latest patch. Opera Mini is also a modern browser but does not support it at all: https://caniuse.com/css-has - As side note, it is already been discussed to deprecate it again. So only sue it if you not have to care about support for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `p:not(:has(*))` to select only `<p>` elements without children.

Comment: Deginitely check support tables for this as it's pretty new. It's universally supported now, but if you need a little bit more support backwards, best to not use it yet. https://caniuse.com/?search=has

Comment: I am actually using the rust crate `scraper`, but looks like it does not support it. I guess I have to write my own logic to filter `<p>` by myself

Comment: Yes, `:has` is relatively new selector, might be not supported...